# Convert a list of dictionaries (with a nested list as values) into a data frame

Tags: python

I would really appreciate some help with this. I am extracting headings and associated list of words under each heading from a website. I have ended up with a list of dictionaries with a value list for each dictionary key:

```
[{'You Led a Project': "['Chaired', 'Controlled', 'Coordinated', 'Executed', 'Headed', 'Operated', 'Orchestrated', 'Organized', 'Oversaw', 'Planned', 'Produced', 'Programmed']"}, {'You Envisioned and Brought a Project to Life': "['Administered', 'Built', 'Charted', 'Created', 'Designed', 'Developed', 'Devised', 'Founded', 'Engineered', 'Established', 'Formalized', 'Formed', 'Formulated', 'Implemented', 'Incorporated', 'Initiated', 'Instituted', 'Introduced', 'Launched', 'Pioneered', 'Spearheaded']"}, {'You Saved the Company Time or Money': "['Conserved', 'Consolidated', 'Decreased', 'Deducted', 'Diagnosed', 'Lessened', 'Reconciled', 'Reduced', 'Yielded']"}, {'You Increased Efficiency, Sales, Revenue, or Customer Satisfaction': "['Accelerated', 'Achieved', 'Advanced', 'Amplified', 'Boosted', 'Capitalized', 'Delivered', 'Enhanced', 'Expanded', 'Expedited', 'Furthered', 'Gained', 'Generated', 'Improved', 'Lifted', 'Maximized', 'Outpaced', 'Stimulated', 'Sustained']"}, {'You Changed or Improved Something': "['Centralized', 'Clarified', 'Converted', 'Customized', 'Influenced', 'Integrated', 'Merged', 'Modified', 'Overhauled', 'Redesigned', 'Refined', 'Refocused', 'Rehabilitated', 'Remodeled', 'Reorganized', 'Replaced', 'Restructured', 'Revamped', 'Revitalized', 'Simplified', 'Standardized', 'Streamlined', 'Strengthened', 'Updated', 'Upgraded', 'Transformed']"}
```

I now want to convert the list into a data frame, such that each item in the value lists are assigned a key. For example:

```
Column 1              Column 2
You Led a Project     Chaired
You Led a Project     Controlled 
....
```

Please my find the code I have so far below:

```
def extract_verbs():
    headers = {'User Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
            Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36'}
    url = "https://www.themuse.com/advice/185-powerful-verbs-that-will-make-your-resume-awesome"
    r2 = requests.get(url, headers)
    verb_soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, "html.parser")
    return verb_soup


def transform_verbs(verb_soup):
    start_numbers = [1, 13, 34, 43, 62, 88, 108, 114, 123, 143, 162, 174]
    section_headings = verb_soup.select("h2")

    for n in range(0,len(start_numbers)-1):
        heading = section_headings[n].getText().split()[3:]
        heading = ' '.join(heading)
        verbs = [item.text for item in verb_soup.find("ol", {"start": start_numbers[n]}).find_all("li")]
        all_verbs = {f"{heading}": f"{verbs}"}
        all_verbs_list.append(all_verbs)
    return


all_verbs_list = []
extract_verb_ouput = extract_verbs()
transform_verbs(extract_verb_ouput)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are the lists (value of dictionaries) really in string format ? just to check

Comment: Hi, yes. I had to change that and then use .from_records() to get the data frame I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the data into a list of records (rows), then construct a dataframe with `.from_records()`:

```py
records = list()
for elem in data:
    for key, value in elem.items():
        for v in value:
            records.append([key, v])
```

```py
>>> records
[['You Led a Project', 'Chaired'],
 ['You Led a Project', 'Controlled'],
 ['You Led a Project', 'Coordinated'],
 ['You Led a Project', 'Executed'],
 ...
```

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=['Column1', 'Column2'])
                              Column1       Column2
0                   You Led a Project       Chaired
1                   You Led a Project    Controlled
2                   You Led a Project   Coordinated
3                   You Led a Project      Executed
4                   You Led a Project        Headed
..                                ...           ...
82  You Changed or Improved Something   Streamlined
83  You Changed or Improved Something  Strengthened
84  You Changed or Improved Something       Updated
85  You Changed or Improved Something      Upgraded
86  You Changed or Improved Something   Transformed
```